# sqLite iOS Commit Failure

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

**Background**: We have an app that has a "schema update" routine.  It basically checks the pragma user_version for sqLite and if the user is running an older schema it updates it to the current dB schema and then updates the pragma version after updating the schema. The code is executed upon startup ( by app delegate) by calling our dbManager code to carry out the schema updates.

**Issue**:  We updated the code (below) to add the changes for next release and as stated update the user_version to 3.  Our issue is that when we do a fresh install of the app (deleting previous versions) we find that the first time you run the app, the code below executes without any errors (we stepped through it tons of times line-by-line) but yet none of the changes are made.  We then exit the app (hit home button), tap the app icon and the code runs again (it didn't update the user_version so it thinks it is running the older schema) and this time all the changes are committed.

**What We Tried**: We have double checked the path of the database to make sure it is correct and it is - we update the same database both times.  We have walk through line by line, we have removed code trying to single out a single line of code.  We have tried to figure out if maybe there is a cache that is not committing the changes, but we have a "finalize" call to force a flush and we are closing our database often to assure we aren't leaving it hanging out.

The code has worked in all previous versions of the app without issue.  The only change we made was to add the "Alter Table" code below.  (We took it out and still had the issue above).  After a couple of days of dead-ends, we are wondering if anyone has seen this or has any ideas?

We are running on the latest release of XCode with iOS 7.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

*Our code...*

....

if (currentlyInstalledDBScehmaVersion < 3) //Upgrade a dbSchema that is prior to version 3
        {

```
        /*
         Upgrade Description:

         All schemas prior to version 3, need to add the evolWarmUpTime and evolCoolDownTime columns to tblPlayerProfile
         */

        @try
        {
            if (sqlite3_open([sfcDatabasePath UTF8String], &dbSFC) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;

                sqlUpgradeCommands = @"ALTER TABLE tblPlayerProfile ADD evolWarmUpTime INTEGER(2) DEFAULT 4";
                const char *sqlQueryAddWarmUp = [sqlUpgradeCommands UTF8String];;

                if  (sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbSFC, sqlQueryAddWarmUp, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
                {
                    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(sqlStatement))NSAssert1(0, @"Error while updating. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(dbSFC));
                }
                sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);

                sqlUpgradeCommands = @"ALTER TABLE tblPlayerProfile ADD evolCoolDownTime INTEGER(2) DEFAULT 5";
                const char *sqlQueryAddCoolDown = [sqlUpgradeCommands UTF8String];;

                if  (sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbSFC, sqlQueryAddCoolDown, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
                {
                    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(sqlStatement))NSAssert1(0, @"Error while updating. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(dbSFC));
                }
                sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);
            }
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception)
        {
            upgradeErrorOccurred = YES;
            NSLog(@"dbManager_SFC:upgradeScheme exception occured: %@", [exception reason]);
        }

        sqlite3_close(dbSFC);
    }

    if (upgradeErrorOccurred == NO)
    {
        [self updateDBVersion:3]; //Upgrade the schema version number!
    }
    [self hideUpgradeAlertFromUser];
```

....

Comment: Are you sure you're referencing the right file the first time?  Is it possible that you open the DB before you do some file initialization?

Comment: Hot Licks - that was the issue - we were not initializing one of our objects at the right time.  We updated our code so that the above routine would initialize the helper object and eliminate the need to be execution order dependent.  Thank you for pointing us in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the issue was related to not initializing an object at the right time.  When the code first executed, the object wasn't initialized, but by exiting and returning, the object was activated by another routine, which created the above described behavior.

We updated our code to assure that object was initialized by the above routine, and not dependent on the order of code execution.

Answer (score 0):

Both `sqlite3_prepare_v2` and  `sqlite3_step` can fail, but you output errors only for the latter.

Use something like this:

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbSFC, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK ||
    sqlite3_step(sqlStatement) != SQLITE_DONE)
{
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error while updating: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(dbSFC));
}
sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);
```

It might be useful to put this into a helper function.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and agree that is a cleaner way to structure the code - unfortunately in implementing your suggestion we didn't get any errors.  It still behaved exactly as we stated above - first run it all executes, but nothing is changed in the schema, second run it executes again and the changes are committed.